# Pin a keyboard shortcut to the Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, shortcuts

I've been using my Windows laptop a lot in tablet mode recently (for drawing) and am growing frustrated whenever I have to click through the tiny edit menu to click undo.

Therefore, I'd like a shortcut on my taskbar (or perhaps make a custom toolbar?) that will execute the keyboard shortcut when I click it.

Off the top of my head, I think this may not be possibly because clicking the shortcut would take focus away from the application that I want to receive the undo command.

I am open to any solution involving "floating buttons" on screen, not necessarily on the task bar, but I believe the issue about focus is probably a game breaker.

Comment: You mean like if you were to just hit `CTRL-z`?

Comment: @EBGreen Yes exactly. I need to reproduce ctrl-z easily onscreen, for when I don't have access to a keyboard.

Comment: I'm sure you could do it with AutoIt and probably with powershell. The problem will be that as soon as you hit the shortcut, the app that you want to undo in will no longer have focus.

Comment: An AutoHotKey script with a slight delay at the beginning to give you time to switch back the focus would do the trick

Comment: If it's always the same app that you're "undoing" in, you can just put a line in your AutoHotkey script to have it activate that app before doing anything else.

Comment: @spoko I didn't think of that as a possibility, but that fits my needs entirely!

Comment: Also note that AHK allows you to use [mouse buttons](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#HotMouse) as triggers, not just keys. So if you have a fourth button you're not using or something, there's that. Or, I haven't done it, but I wonder if you might be able to set a combination of multiple simultaneous mouse buttons as the trigger for AHK. Remember also that you can make it program-specific.